# I am unable to host my website in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql .. I used this command to install php in my system but while hhosting into EC2 instance it shows the list of files into the chrome and won't run php files

Comment: Have you checked this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Answer (score 0):

I am done with solution, there was problem in configuring the security group settings of the database and by default the page considered is index.html or index.php